# select certain value then output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file containing mixed information while I only need certain columns of them.

Below is my example file.

```
A B C D       
1 2 3 abcdef   
5 6 7 abcdef  
1 2 3 abcdef
```

And I want to extract the file to get the information I need. For example, looks like below in my output file.

```
A C D       # I only need A, C, and D column.
1 3 ab      # For D column, I only need ab.
5 7 ab      
1 3 ab
```

It is not a csv or txt file, but with a space between each column.

Comment: If it's not a text file, what kind of file is it?

Comment: I think OP is talking about the extension, not the format.

Answer (score 6):

You can still read a space-separated file with csv module by using the delimiter kwarg:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/data.txt') as f:
...    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=' ')
...    for row in reader:
...        print row['A'], row['C'], row['D'][:2]
...         
1 3 ab
5 7 ab
1 3 ab
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I have hundreds of columns like column D required to be selected, the select criterion is the same (i.e. [:2]) do you have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Make a list of those columns, and then loop over it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something generical for managing data structures the easiest thing you can do is use python libraries to ease the job.

You can use Pandas Lib: Python Data Analysis Library to rapidly parse the file to a [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) that provides methods to make what you want.

You also need Numpy lib because as_matrix method (below) returns a numpyArray.

You can see your data file as a csv (Comma separated value) file with spaces as separators.

With pd you can easily parse the file with read_csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataFrame = pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep = ' ')
```

For selecting columns you use as_matrix method:

```
selection = dataFrame.as_matrix((A,C,D))
```

Then you probably want to can cast it back to dataFrame to continue using its methods:

```
newDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(selection)
```

Dropping "cdef" of the "abcdef" values in the column D looks like a thing that can be solved by a simple **for**, and using [**String**][5] methods provided by Python. Its a very particular instruction and i don't know any implemented method of any library that accomplishes this.

I hope i helped you.

PD: I tried to post a lot of links but the system didn't let me. I recomend you to look for Numpy and Pandas in Google if you dont have them. 
You should check the pandas DataFrame docs to check the methods. I the case you didn't understand what i did look for pandas.read_csv, pandas.dataFrame.as_matrix docs in Google.

And if you don't know how to operate Strings look in Python docs for String.

Edit: Anyway, if you don't want to use libs you can parse the txt file to a list of lists imitating a matrix or using the csv structure that wim mentions in his answer. Then create a function to drop columns, checking the first element of every column (Column identifier) and with some **for**s export that to other matrix.

Then create another function that deletes the desired values of a column, with some other **for**s.

The point is that using functions to accomplish what you want makes the solution generical for any table managed as a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one columns like D and want to do the same thing as D, you can do below if you're ok with selecting columns with indices instead of letters:

```
# your data like this
A B C D E
1 2 3 abcdef abbbb
5 6 7 abcdef abbbb
1 2 3 abcdef abbbb
```

You `import csv` then

```
>>> with open('yourdata.txt') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row[0], row[1], *[c[:2] for c in row[3:]])
... 
A B D E
1 2 ab ab
5 6 ab ab
1 2 ab ab
```

The `*` operator before the `[c[:2] for c in row[3:]]` is for list argument unpacking. `*` basicly converts `[1,2,3]` into `1,2,3`, so `print(*[1,2,3])` is identical to `print(1,2,3)`. Works on tuples as well.

However, this is python3. If you are using python2, `print` will give you syntax error, but you can make a wrapper function that takes in the unpacked list arguments, and replace `print` with this function:

```
def myprint(*args): 
    print ' '.join([str(i) for i in args])
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows error message, 'Syntax error while detecting tuple'. Any suggestion?

Comment: @BigSecrect I just realized I'm using python3 and you are using python 2.7, in which print behaves differently and list unpacking can only be used in function arguments. So it might be a bit of overkill but you can do this:  `def p(*args): print ' '.join([str(i) for i in args])` then replace the `print` part with this function.